# C++ error: invalid use of ‘::’ for `std::cout`

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang++

This is probably the weirdest thing I have seen in the last few years.

I have a project that builds perfectly well in two completely different machines (openSUSE Tumbleweed and ubuntu 14.04).
I started with a new machine using kubuntu 16.04 and this error started happening:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 cout_qualif.cpp -lpng -o cout_qualif
In file included from cout_qualif.cpp:1:0:
debug_utils.h:19:19: error: invalid use of ‘::’
 # define msg std::cout
```

Clang also points an error, but with a quite different message:

```
$ clang -std=c++14 cout_qualif.cpp -lpng -o cout_qualif
In file included from cout_qualif.cpp:3:
In file included from /usr/include/png++/png.hpp:34:
In file included from /usr/include/png.h:317:
/usr/include/zlib.h:94:19: error: non-friend class member 'cout' cannot have a qualified name
    z_const char *msg;  /* last error message, NULL if no error */
                  ^~~
./debug_utils.h:19:19: note: expanded from macro 'msg'
#       define  msg     std::cout
                        ~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

The simplest test code I've came across is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "debug_utils.h"
#include <png++/png.hpp>

int main()
{
    msg << "Start" << std::endl;

    png::image< png::rgb_pixel > image("input.png");
    image.write("output.png");


    msg << "Finish" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And "debug_utils.h":

```
#ifndef DEBUG_UTILS_H
#define DEBUG_UTILS_H

#include <iostream>

#   define  msg std::cout

#endif // DEBUG_UTILS_H
```

It turns out that "png.h" includes "zlib.h" and there is defined a struct:

```
typedef struct z_stream_s {
// ...
   z_const char *msg;  /* last error message, NULL if no error */
```

This `msg` member is what is triggering the error. If I move my `#include "debug_utils.h"` one line below, after `#include <png++/png.hpp>`, everything seems to work fine.

---

**Now finally the question:
Why this machine cannot compile my code while two other can?**

---

Additional info:

```
Kubuntu 16.04:
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

$ clang --version
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)

openSUSE Tumbleweed:
g++ is 7.1.1

Ubuntu 14.04:
Exact version not available at hand but I believe it is 4.9.x
```

Comment: Probably on the other machine, `<png++/png.hpp>` doesn't have a `msg` member variable

Comment: Seriously, why would you ever think that code like `#   define  msg std::cout` is a good idea? It will break any code that contains the name `msg`, which is not that uncommon a name, in my experience.

Comment: It seems to me like `#define msg std::cout` is begging for trouble, and now you've finally found it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, since you were so concerned in spoting a bad code, woudln't you also be willing to answer the question, please? Which mechanisms might lead the very same code to work in two machines and not in a third one?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I repeat my words for Neil, woudln't you also be willing to answer the question, please?

Comment: As Justin said, perhaps the headers have changed?

Comment: @fljx No, I can't answer the question. I don't know exactly why it works on some systems but not others. I can at best guess. If I *could* answer the question, I would have. But, have you considered doing away with `debug_utils.h` and being done with it?

Comment: @Justin, thanks for replying. I checked and zlib defines the same `msg` since ever. The only change is from version 1.2.6 and on the added `z_const` qualifier over `char *msg`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, of course yes. I believe you understand we live in a world where projects are not developed by a single person anymore and having to control whether each programmer in my team has a good sense for naming is not something one can catch all the time. The point here is not a symbol name, but what might be hiding behind to let such a code compile.

Comment: You may be approaching this from the wrong direction. Is png++ always following the same include path across all of your machines?

Comment: Fired up an opensuse VM. Installed png++. Ran `cpp -M -I/usr/include test.cpp > out`. Grepped for zlib in out. Got no hits. Looks like there is a different chain of includes and it doesn't include zlib.h.  No zlib.h, no macro substitution in zlib.h.

Comment: @user4581301 it seems to be a good shot. Unfortunatelly I cannot test the Ubuntu machine right now, but I believe you found out the right answer. Please post it so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap the cause of the problem

```
#   define  msg std::cout
```

in debug_utils.h substitutes `std::cout` for any instances of `msg` throughout the code after debug_utils.h is included. As `msg` is a common short identifier, particularly for a message buffer, an unintended substitution has always been a risk lurking in the code. The solution to this is obvious: Don't do that. Use a longer, less likely to be duplicated substitution or don't do it at all and replace the macro. Without seeing your usecase I'd probably replace the macro with a function that returns the correct stream and the compiler can easily inline.

The confusion and the question stems from why an error from the macro substitution only arises from a simple piece of test code when compiled on only one of three candidate PCs.

The answer is differences in the toolchain and support libraries. For one reason or another, on only one of these PCs a third-party header that uses the `msg` identifier is included by a third-party header included by the test program. The other two follow different inclusion paths to build the same program and avoid tripping over the unwanted substitution.